# GridView dosen't display image from web server

Tags: android

I created an application that will get pictures and display it in a GridView.
the image is base64 encode on data base and in my application I decode the image.
I use jtds.jar library file to connect coma database
the application works fine when the server is local
when is on the web server, the images do not appear on Gridview.
Tanks for the help.

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

```
ConnectionClass connectionClass;

GridView gridView;
```

// ProgressBar pbbar;

```
MenuProdutoAdapter adapter;

public HomeFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    connectionClass = new ConnectionClass();



        FillGrid fillGrid = new FillGrid();
        fillGrid.execute("");

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Internet nao esta disponivel", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    gridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridView1);

 //   pbbar = (ProgressBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pbbar);
 //   pbbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment


    return rootView;
}


@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
}


public class FillGrid extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    String z = "";

    List<MenuProdutos> menuProdutosList = new ArrayList<MenuProdutos>();


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

     //   pbbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String r) {

      //  pbbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),r, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        adapter = new MenuProdutoAdapter(HomeFragment.this, menuProdutosList);

        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String pid = menuProdutosList.get(position).getProdutoMenu_ID();

                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Produtos "
                                + (position + 1) + ": " + menuProdutosList.get(position).getProdutoMenu_nome()
                                + "E o seu PID eh: " + pid,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

//                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), FriendsActivity.class);
//                    intent.putExtra("pid", pid);
//                    startActivity(intent);

```
                displayView(position);

                }
        }   );


    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {
            Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();
            if (con == null) {
                z = "Error in connection with SQL server";
            } else {
                String query = "select * from ImagemMenu";
                PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
                ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();


                while (rs.next()) {

                    String Menupro_ID = rs.getString("Id");
                    String Menupro_nome = rs.getString("Nome");
                    String Menupro_image = rs.getString("Imagem");


                    byte[] decodeString = Base64.decode(Menupro_image, Base64.DEFAULT);
                    Bitmap Menupro_bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodeString,
                            0, decodeString.length);

                    MenuProdutos p = new MenuProdutos(Menupro_ID, Menupro_nome, Menupro_bitmap);

                    menuProdutosList.add(p);

                }



                z = "Success";
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            z = "Error retrieving data from table";

        }
        return z;
    }
}
```

Comment: use http://square.github.io/picasso/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1) import Picasso from square in gradle

`compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

2) get your imageView and load the picture from a url like here

```
 Picasso.with(context).load("http://your_uri").into(imageView);
```

I hope this help

http://square.github.io/picasso/ <- other instructions here

And if you don't like Picasso you can use "Universal Image Loader" https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader or Glide https://github.com/bumptech/glide.